# problem with createTab

Tags: iphone, button, view, titanium, appcelerator

I have a problem with a window that contains a TabGroups "there are 5 tabs"

the window and there appears that the window of the first tab that appears but when I clik on anything else happens.

I have a main window that contains views and each view refers to a file js

js file contents that I have after clicking my view is the one I just posted

In addition to the icons of the tab does not appear as

Another concern the back button when I click on it nothing happens and I can not assign an image to this button here

can you help me please

here is the code

```
    // this sets the background color of the master UIView (when there are no windows/tab groups on it)
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('white');

// create tab group
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({ 
    barColor:'black'
});

// create base UI tab and root window

var win1= Titanium.UI.createWindow({ 
    //modal:true,leftNavButton:boutonRetour, // ajout bouton retour
    title:'Récentes',
    backgroundColor:'white'
});


//win.add(boutonRetour);// bouton retour 

var var1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    icon:'images/icons/recentes_off.png',
    title:'var1',
   window:win1
});




var win2= Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'var2',
    backgroundColor:'white'
});


var var2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    //icon:'recentes_on.png',
    title:'var2',
    window:win2
});





var win3= Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
   title:'var3',
    backgroundColor:'white'
});

var var3 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    //icon:'recentes_on.png',
    title:'Thèmes',
    window:win3
});



var win4 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'var4',
    backgroundColor:'white'
});

var var4 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    //icon:'recentes_on.png',
    title:'var4',
    window:win4


});




var win5 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'var5',
    backgroundColor:'white'
});


var var5 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
   // icon:'recentes_on.png',
    title:'var5',
    window:win5
});



//  add tabs------------------------------------------

tabGroup.addTab(var1); 
tabGroup.addTab(var2);
tabGroup.addTab(var3); 
tabGroup.addTab(var4);
tabGroup.addTab(var5); 


// open tab group-----------------------------------------
tabGroup.open(); 

// -------------------ajout bouton Retour --------------------

var ButtonRetour = Ti.UI.createButtonBar({
  labels:           ['Retour'],
  backgroundColor:  '#ae4041',
  backgroundImage: 'images/back.png',
  color:            '#ffffff'
});            

ButtonRetour.addEventListener('click', function(){
    win.close();
});

win1.leftNavButton = ButtonRetour;

// ---------------fin --------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

none of your windows have a URL to tell Ti where to get the js file

```
Ti.UI.createWindow({
    url: 'link/to/js/file.js',
    title: 'Window Title',
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});
```

each of your windows defined need to have a URL if you are going to link to them by added them to a tab like so `window: win1`

as for the icon no showing up the image path is probably incorrect.

Comment: i found the solution I added this line of code in my app.js ////////        vodView.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    Ti.include('window_main/vod.js'); //////////////   thank you :(

Comment: Though that may work I believe it's more memory intense because you included the page each time rather then caching it and then showing and hiding it.